# Proof of the application of a Substitution on a term

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am trying to proof that the application of an empty Substitution on a term is equal to the given term.
Here is the code:

```
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Require Import Coq.Arith.EqNat.
Require Import Recdef.
Require Import Omega.
Import ListNotations.
Set Implicit Arguments.



Inductive Term : Type :=
   | Var  : nat -> Term
   | Fun  : string  -> list Term -> Term.


Definition Subst : Type := list (nat*Term).



Definition maybe{X Y: Type} (x : X) (f : Y -> X) (o : option Y): X :=
   match o with
    |None   => x
    |Some a => f a
   end.

Fixpoint lookup {A B : Type} (eqA : A -> A -> bool) (kvs : list (A * B)) (k : A) : option B :=
   match kvs with
    |[]          => None
    |(x,y) :: xs => if eqA k x then Some y else lookup eqA  xs k
   end.
```

I am trying to proof some properties of this function.

```
Fixpoint apply (s : Subst) (t : Term) : Term :=
   match t with
    | Var x     => maybe (Var x) id (lookup beq_nat s x )
    | Fun f ts => Fun f (map (apply s ) ts)
   end.


Lemma empty_apply_on_term:
  forall t, apply [] t = t.
Proof.
intros.
induction t.
reflexivity.
```

I am stuck after the reflexivity. I wanted to do induction on the list build in a term but if i do so i'ĺl get stuck in a loop. 
i will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the automatically generated inductive principle for the `Term` type is too weak, because it has another inductive type `list` inside it (specifically, `list` is applied to the very type being constructed). Adam Chlipala's CPDT gives a good explanation of what's going on, as well as an example of how to manually build a better inductive principle for such types in the [inductive types chapter](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/InductiveTypes.html#lab32). I've adapted his example `nat_tree_ind'` principle for your `Term` inductive, using the builtin `Forall` rather than a custom definition. With it, your theorem becomes easy to prove:

```
Section Term_ind'.
  Variable P : Term -> Prop.

  Hypothesis Var_case : forall (n:nat), P (Var n).

  Hypothesis Fun_case : forall (s : string) (ls : list Term),
      Forall P ls -> P (Fun s ls).

  Fixpoint Term_ind' (tr : Term) : P tr :=
    match tr with
    | Var n => Var_case n
    | Fun s ls =>
      Fun_case s
               ((fix list_Term_ind (ls : list Term) : Forall P ls :=
                   match ls with
                   | [] => Forall_nil _
                   | tr'::rest => Forall_cons tr' (Term_ind' tr') (list_Term_ind rest)
                   end) ls)
    end.

End Term_ind'.


Lemma empty_apply_on_term:
  forall t, apply [] t = t.
Proof.
  intros.
  induction t using Term_ind'; simpl; auto.
  f_equal.
  induction H; simpl; auto.
  congruence.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a typical trap for beginners.  The problem is that your definition of `Term` has a recursive occurrence inside another inductive type -- in this case, `list`.  Coq does not generate a useful inductive principle for such types, unfortunately; you have to program your own.  Adam Chlipala's CDPT [has a chapter on inductive types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/InductiveTypes.html) that describes the problem. Just look for "nested inductive types".